# TTFB definition is not the same between chrome dev tools and web.dev, which is correct?

Tags: google-chrome, web, networking, browser

[chrome says](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation) TTFB not including DNS\TCP time:

[image]

But [web.dev says](https://web.dev/ttfb/) it should include DNS\TCP time:

[image]

I'm confused, which one is correct, please help.

Comment: Correct for what purpose?  Are you trying to optimize your user experience or your server's ability to quickly fulfill requests once it receives them?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No specific purpose, just tying to dig every bit of web performance metrics. I thought these two TTFB is the same concept. since they're fulfilling two different purpose, the inconsistent is ok to me now. Thank you for your comment.